# Como criar um loader enquanto a página não é toda processada após o retorno do AJAX?

Tags: jquery, css, html5, ajax

Olá.

Tenho um código que faz uma consulta ao banco de dados (ao carregar a página) para preencher uma tabela (Isso é feito via AJAX).

Eu criei uma div que contém um gif de um loader e ela é exibida enquanto o AJAX preenche a página. E depois desaparece quando todas as linhas da tabela são preenchidas.

O problema que acontece é que o loader desaparece, porém eu olho no console, e os dados da página não foram completamente preenchidos. Apenas as linhas da tabela foram exibidas.

Se eu, por exemplo, for alterar uma linha da tabela, a alteração não consegue ser executada porque a página não foi completamente carregada.

A minha situação e a seguinte: Eu gostaria que o loader desaparecesse apenas quando a página TODA terminar de carregar.

**Se abaixo o código utilizado.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // AO CARREGAR A PÁGINA, CHAMAR A FUNÇÃO QUE PREENCHE AS EMPRESAS

  $(function() {
    preencher_empresas();

  });

  function preencher_empresas() {

    $("div#loading").html("<img src='_imagens/load.gif' width='100px'>");

    $.ajax({
      //dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      url: "banco/banco-vision/pagina-cadastrar-empresas/preencher-empresas.php",
      cache: false,

    }).done(function(data) {

      $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, emp) {
        $("div#loading").html("<img src='_imagens/load.gif' width='100px'>");
        //CRIANDO AS LINHAS COM OS TD DA TABELA QUE SÃO O RESULTADO NA CONSULTA AO BANCO 

        $('<tr>', {
          id: emp.codigo
        }).appendTo('#registros-empresas-cadastradas');
        $('<td>', {
          html: emp.COD
        }).appendTo('tr#' + emp.codigo);
        $('<td>', {
          html: emp.EMPRESA
        }).appendTo('tr#' + emp.codigo);
        $('<td>', {
          html: emp.TRIBUTACAO
        }).appendTo('tr#' + emp.codigo);
        barra_progresso = $('<td>').appendTo('tr#' + emp.codigo);
        $(barra_progresso).addClass("info-progress");
        td_botao_alterar = $('<td>', {
          style: "text-align:center"
        }).appendTo('tr#' + emp.codigo);

        a_botao_alterar = $('<a>', {
          href: "#",
          html: "Alterar"
        }).appendTo(td_botao_alterar);
        $(a_botao_alterar).addClass("btn btn-md btn-success");
        $(a_botao_alterar).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        $(a_botao_alterar).attr('data-target', '#modal-alterar-empresas');

        //Criando div progresso
        div_progress = $('<div>', {
          style: "margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px ;background:black;"
        }).appendTo(barra_progresso);
        $(div_progress).addClass("progress progress-striped");

        //Criando div progresso 2
        div_progress_2 = $('<div>').appendTo(div_progress);
        $(div_progress_2).addClass("div-progress2 progress-bar progress-bar-success");
        $(div_progress_2).addClass("_" + emp.COD);
        $(div_progress_2).attr("role", "progressbar");

        progressBar(emp.COD);


      });

      $("div#loading").hide();




      /*
      $('#registros-empresas-cadastradas').html(empresas);
      */

    }).fail(function() {
      alert('Falha na listagem dos usuários');

    }).always(function() {

    });

  }

  function progressBar(empresa_cod) {


    $.ajax({
      url: "banco/banco-vision/pagina-cadastrar-empresas/conta-concluidos.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        empresa_cod: empresa_cod
      },
      cache: false

    }).done(function(return_emp) {

      var contador_progresso = $.parseJSON(return_emp);

      console.log(contador_progresso);

      if (contador_progresso.vazio == false) {
        $("._" + empresa_cod).css("width", contador_progresso.concluidos.toFixed(2) + "%");
        $("._" + empresa_cod).html(contador_progresso.concluidos.toFixed(2) + "%");
      } else {
        $("div._" + empresa_cod).removeClass("progress-bar-success");
        $("div._" + empresa_cod).addClass("progress-bar-primary");
        $("._" + empresa_cod).css("width", "100%");
        $("._" + empresa_cod).html("Não Possui");
      }


    }).fail(function() {
      console.log("Erro ao preencher a barra de progresso");

    }).always(function() {


    });


  }


});
```

```html
<!-- CÓDIGO DE PREENCHIMENTO DA TABELA E DO LOADER -->

<div id="loading" style="position: absolute;top: 0px;left: 0px;z-index: 100;"></div>

<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" id="listagem-empresas">

  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="resultado-empresas-cadastradas">

    <thead class="">
      <tr>
        <th>COD</th>
        <th>EMPRESAS</th>
        <th>TRIBUTAÇÃO</th>
        <th>PROGRESSO</th>
        <th>ALTERAR</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="registros-empresas-cadastradas">



    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" id="incluir-nova-empresas">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" id="incluir-empresa" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-incluir-empresas"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> INCLUIR NOVA EMPRESA</button>
</div>
```

**ABAIXO UMA IMAGEM DO LOADER APARECENDO ANTES DAS LINHAS SEREM PREENCHIDAS**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**ABAIXO UMA IMAGEM DA  PÁGINA APÓS A TABELA APARECER (PORÉM ANTES DE CARREGAR TODA)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fala ai, @Sam . As barras variam. Essas barras são referente aos status das atividades concluidas de cada empresa.

Comment: Se você descer a tabela toda, logo que carregar a página e após o loader desaparecer, você perceberá que as barras não foram completamente preenchidas, elas ainda estão "enchendo".

Comment: Não, as vezes as TD já estão todas completas mas as barras ainda não estão preenchidas.

Comment: Na verdade, eu gostaria que o "loader" só desaparecesse quando as barras fossem completamente "enchidas".

Comment: Adicionei a função lá no código.

Comment: Entendi agora. A cada each do primeiro Ajax vc chama a função para cada barra de progresso. Só vejo uma solução pra isso, usar um setInterval para verificar quando todas estão preenchidas.

Comment: Vou abrir um chat, pq ficar debatendo código aqui nos comentários não é permitido.

Comment: Entra lá: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93644/thiago-petherson-e-sam

Comment: Jé pensou em utilizar um beforeSend?

Comment: @thiago dias, before e send não funcionou. Continuou dando o mesmo problema.